# Execute sql statement by passing sql column names as arguments through function

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

```
Public Function fetchUserInfo(columnnames As String)
    strsQL = "SELECT name,address FROM userInfo.csv"
end function
```

If inside the function `fetchUserInfo`, above SQL statement, I directly give column names like `name, address`, it retrieves the result.

When passing a parameter/arguments column names in the function and using the arguments in sql statement, it shows this error:

> no value given for one or more parameters in vba macro

```
Sub user()
Dim sqlColumnNames As String
sqlColumnNames = "name,address"
fetchUserInfo sqlColumnNames 
EndSub

Public Function fetchUserInfo(columnnames As String)
    strsQL = "SELECT  " & columnnames & " FROM userInfo.csv"
End Function
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of the information being passed in the `columnnames` argument. Also, since you tag `macos` which version of Office is this?

Comment: Version  is  Microsoft office professional plus 2016

Comment: Looking at your code in isolation is difficult, but I suspect the issue might be tied to either the scope of the variable `strSQL` or because the function `fetchUserInfo` has no return value. Is `strSQL` a module level variable?

Comment: You is either incomplete or makes no sense. Please provide your working code.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
Sub user()
Dim sqlColumnNames As String, strSQL As String

sqlColumnNames = "name,address"
strSQL = fetchUserInfo(sqlColumnNames)
MsgBox strSQL

End Sub

Public Function fetchUserInfo(columnnames As String) As String
    fetchUserInfo = "SELECT  " & columnnames & " FROM userInfo.csv"
End Function
```